# View list of users

Tags: users

I would like to see how many users are on my system. How could I view a list of all the users on the system?

Comment: i think `/etc/passwd` would help you.

Comment: Do you mean how many user accounts are on the system, or how many users are currently logged in?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get a list of all users with

```
getent passwd | cut -d':' -f1
```

This selects the first column (user name) of the system user database. In contrast to solutions parsing `/etc/passwd`, this will work regardless of the type of database used (traditional `/etc/passwd`, LDAP, etc). Note that this list includes system users as well (e.g. nobody, mail, etc.).

The exact user number can be determined as follows:

```
getent passwd | wc -l
```

A list of currently logged in users can be obtained with the `users` or `who` command:

```
users  # or
who
```

Comment: Why not use `getent passwd` to get the current user list, including users found via LDAP etc.? Also, `wc -l` would be a far shorter way to count the lines in `/etc/passwd` (or the output of `getent passwd`, for that matter).

Comment: @n.st That's better indeed. I included the change in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That will not necessarily list all the user's.  Some user databases can be made non-enumeratable

Answer (score 4):

You could simply `cat` the `/etc/passwd` file or use,

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

To cut the first field of the same file, it'd list the names you're expecting.
Additonally, `w` `who` and `finger` would help you with who all are logged in from which locations/tty and their activity details.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sed 's/:.*//g' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: You could also remove the global flag if you want to.